# Dynamic input modifiers in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have an input like so:

```
<input type="number" :value="key" @input.number="setValue" />
```

I would like for the `.number` input modifier to be dynamic and linked to a variable, such that I can change it based on the `input type` (which in my instance can be either `number` or `text`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use input modifier like that you can always create a custom component which receives `type` and `value` as props and emits value on `@input` -

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="type=='number'">
      <input :type="type" :value="key" @input.number="setValue" />
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <input :type="type" :value="key" @input="setValue">
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just have a handler that does that logic for you in the function.

```
@input="setValue($event.target.value)"
```

```
methods: {
     setValue (input) {
          if (typeof input === 'number') {
                              //do something
                            }
          if (typeof input === 'string') {
                              //do something
                            }
     }
}
```

You can use any type of check you want to, not necessarily `typeof`.

Comment: Yeah... this is what I ended up going with. I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, I highly recommend for better practice of using a v-model on that input instead of passing the `$event.target.value` if you aren't already.

Comment: Yes, totally agree :)